# Arrays subtle behaviour in Java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
class B {

    int i;

    B(int i) {
    this.i = i;
    }

     public String toString() {
          return "i = " + this.i;
       }
}

 public class MainClass{

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            B [] x = new B[2];
            x[0] = new B(90);
            x[1] = new B(100);
            B obj = new B(10);
            System.out.println(obj);
                    System.out.println(x);//toString method of class B is not called here.

    }
}
```

//When i printed obj the toString method of B class was called but when I tried to print x it was not called.Can anybody explain why!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the `toString` method of the [Array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) class was called, and Array does not override the Object `toString()` - so you get a class name and (essentially) a reference address. What you wanted was probably [Arrays.toString(Object[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) - like so,

```
// System.out.println(x); // <-- calls toString of java.lang.Array
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
```

Comment: I know after Arrays.toString(x) correct info will be printed, but why does not it called toString() method of class B when I only printed x.

Comment: @Aamir Edited to answer you more directly.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not automatically invoke `toString` on the members of an array. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415604/tostring-java-of-arrays), you want `Arrays.toString(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're printing the array itself, not the individual elements of the array.  Arrays are objects, too, but they don't override [`toString()` from `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29).  Try

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
```

Comment: Careful! Java arrays are objects in a general sort of way, but they are not _Objects_ as defined by the Java language spec.

Comment: @jameslarge What would `x instanceof Object` yield?  `true`.

Comment: @jameslarge Why do you think so?

Comment: @jameslarge Yes they are.

Comment: Oops!  I stand corrected.  I was thinking about how the langage treats array references somewhat differently from the way it treats other object references, and I probably had some old C++ thoughts rattling around in my head as well.